# Flask does not loads css with url_for()

Tags: flask

I am writing a flask web application that needs to have css. I have used the correct syntax, i think.

my web application is at its start and the css is simple too. I don't know why the flask won't load my css.

the code i used to link css to the html file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='style.css')}}">
```

[image contains file structure, code and localhost browser image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzlJz.png)

Comment: Hello Shubhashish, welcome to Stackoverflow. Include the Python code and template with proper code format in the question.Here is [official documentation of Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) to use code formatting inside question.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting HTTP 404 errors trying to get `/static/static/style.css`. You have the line correctly in the question here, but in the Jinja template (on the screenshot), it reads:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='/static/style.css')}}">
```

i.e. there's `/static/` added in the `filename`. Remove it and make it read

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='style.css')}}">
```